# Creating Custom Operations and Controllers Example does not work

Tags: api-platform.com

I just tried the https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#recommended-method example.

1. I generated the `Book.class` as described
2. Add `CreateBookPublication` class
3. If I invoke the API I receive the following error:

> (1/1) RuntimeException
>       Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\CreateBookPublication": argument "$bookPublishingHandler" of method "__construct()" has type
>   "App\Controller\BookPublishingHandler" but this class was not found.

Do you have any idea?
I would like to generate an own hardcoded response without doctrine for test purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `BookPublishingHandler` class, you must implement it yourself, this docs example is not fully working demo.

Error says DI trying to find `App\Controller\CreateBookPublication` but it's not exists or it's not registered as service. I assume you are using default configuration and it is register services found in `src/` directory automatically.

So create directory `src/Handler`, inside create class file BookPublishingHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Handler;

use App\Entity\Book;

class BookPublishingHandler
{
    public function handle(Book $book): array
    {
        // your logic for publishing book or/and eg. return your custom data
    }
}
```

and add import to your CreateBookPublication controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Handler\BookPublishingHandler;
```

Or you can just for test return hardcoded array directly from controller.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. I still have a problems.

Comment: @Ludi I updated answer, you must put your `BookPublishingHandler` class inside `src/` folder, in my example `src/Handler/`

Comment: Hi, 
Now it seems, that it works fine. 

I still have one question. Why is it necessary to create CreateBookPublication Controller and the BookPublishingHandler Handler? I easily could place all code in the Controller.

Comment: It is not necessary, you can do all the work in controller, but it good practice to separate code into classes with single responsibility (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), it's first one of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID principles